# Creating a std::vector of derived classes

Tags: c++, stdvector, derived-class

Assume that I have an Abstract Class

```
class AbstractClass {
public:
    virtual int get() const = 0;
};
```

and two different Derived classes

```
class DerivedClassA : public AbstractClass {
public:
    int get() const override { return 1; }
};

class DerivedClassB : public AbstractClass {
public:    
    int get() const override { return 2; }
};
```

and I want to pass a `std::vector` of Abstract Classed to a given function:

```
int f(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractClass> >& classes) { ... }
```

What I'm doing is this:

```
int main () {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractClass> > _classes;
    std::shared_ptr<AbstractClass> _derivedA = std::make_shared<DerivedClassA>();
    _classes.push_back(_derivedA);
    std::shared_ptr<AbstractClass> _derivedB = std::make_shared<DerivedClassB>();
    _classes.push_back(_derivedB);
    std::cout << f(_classes) << "\n";
}
```

It does work but I'm wondering if there is a more compact form to write it in modern C++? I've tried using `auto` in some places but it always gives an error, or to build the derived classes in place, but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractClass>> _classes {std::make_shared<DerivedClassA>(), std::make_shared<DerivedClassB>()};` is probably the most compact.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: or even `f({std::make_shared<DerivedClassA>(), std::make_shared<DerivedClassB>()});`.

Answer (score 6):

> It does work but I'm wondering if there is a more compact form to write it

You could get rid of the intermediate variables to make it more compact:

```
f({
    std::make_shared<DerivedClassA>(), 
    std::make_shared<DerivedClassB>(),
});
```

Since all access specifiers are public, you can make the class definitions more compact by using `struct`:

```
struct DerivedClassB : AbstractClass {
    int get() const override { return 1; }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Besides what @eeronika is suggesting, you can also implicitly call `std::shared_ptr` constructor by passing raw pointers:

```
int main () {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractClass> > _classes;
    _classes.emplace_back(new DerivedClassA);
    _classes.emplace_back(new DerivedClassB);
    std::cout << f(_classes) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea and will leak the objects if the vector reallocation fails.

Comment: You're right, this isn't the best practice for creating `shared_ptr`s, but this scenario is not an issue if you `reserve()` enough space upfront or if you don't catch `std::bad_alloc` and let your app fail immediately